# How to pass arguments while while executing a Python script from inside another Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm executing a python script

```
 subprocess.call("/home/scripts/secondary.py", shell=True)
```

from inside my primary.py script situated at the same location.Now, I want to pass multiple arguments to the secondary.py. I have doubts pertaining to two things-

1)How do I pass the arguments and **use them in the secondary script**?

I've trying to pass them as--

```
     import subprocess

     subprocess.call("/home/scripts/secondary.py", "arg1", "arg2",shell=True)
```

But, having difficulties as to how do I use the passed variables.Also, I don't know if it's the correct way or not.

Comment: Please be clearer about the difficulties you are having.  You can only pass string text values on the command-line.  Are you trying to *share* variables?

Comment: Hi, I want to pass arguments like A and B for reference and do some meanignful operations.I'm passing arguments A and B as command line arguments in the primary script and calling the seconadary script from inside primary script.

Comment: I still don't understand what difficulties you meet for this purpose.

Comment: Okay,I'll try to be clearer this time. The difficulties I'm facing is  

1) I want to know if  the below is the correct way to pass the arguments.
subprocess.call("/home/scripts/secondary.py", "arg1", "arg2",shell=True)


2)And secondly,once in secondary.py can I directly use the arguments like arg1 and arg2..or do I need to retrieve it from a argv[] list.